# How can I secure my custom transferFrom function?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, decentralized-exchange

My `transferFrom` function is implemented like this.

```
myAddress = 0x0; // my address

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    uint256 fee;
    fee = amount.div(10000);
    _transfer(from, myAddress, fee);
    _transfer(from, to, amount.sub(fee));
return true;
}
```

I tested it and any address can execute this function and it could be dangerous and empty people's wallets.

I tried to add

```
require(from == msg.sender);
```

It's secured but it prevents other contracts to transfer.

Comment: Why not just use OpenZeppelin's [ERC-20 implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I need fees., there aren't in ERC-20 `transferFrom`.

Comment: still, you can start from OpenZeppelin's implementation and work your way up from there.

Comment: To implement fees, you need to work with percentages, for which you need a fixed-point number representation (floating points do not exist in Solidity). I recommend taking a look at my math library [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an onlyOwner modifier to sensitive functions

you have to set an owner state variable, preferably on deployment and add couple of functions.
They are very familiar patterns, and you should use OpenZeppelin's ownable contract. May as well look at reentrancy too. Perhaps a function to change/add owner(s)

But the basic gist of it is this

```
//state variable
address owner;

constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function isOwner() external returns (bool) {
    return msg.sender == owner;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(isOwner(), "Only owner allowed");
    _;
}

function sensitiveFunc() external onlyOwner {
    // sensitive operations
}
```

Comment: onlyOwner will prevent a function to be called by a contract I think.

Comment: a contract can be an owner. 
in the code above, it would have to be deployed by that contract.
if more than one owner needed, the code would need a couple of changes and a function to set additional owners

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the ERC20 documentation to understand what the standard is about before posting questions.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol

You need to store allowances on-chain, a way to see whether `address_A` has allowed/approved `address_B` to spend its tokens.

ERC20 dictates a function pair `allowance(from, caller)` and `approve(spender, amount)` to handle this.